# Error while trying to run my app on an emulator: >Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug

Tags: java, android

I am currently coding on a project and need some help. As in the title mentioned I get an Error when try running the app on the emulator:

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/firebase/appindexing/Action$Builder.class
>   I hope someone knows a fix for this problem, thanks for upcoming suggestions.

Here's my gradle in case you need it:

```
>apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.devis.de.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v7'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
}
```

Comment: try to run ./gradlew clean then build again

Comment: It says /gradlew isn't found in my root project

Comment: if you have no gradle wrapper just run gradle clean

Comment: didn't work, still gets the same error popping up. additionally it gets a new error: Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'arm' CPU

Comment: So, after hours of searching for an answer, I came across various ansewers for errors showing up atfer i cleaned another error. And then finally my app started working fluently again.